# How to intercept or pause http status code 301 request in a browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, http-status-code-301, data-integrity

I am looking for a solution to interrupt or pause a 301 ( redirect ) request in Chrome dev tools. My scenario is I have an API integration with a local payment gateway which requires 301 redirect to their server ( HTTP GET and then redirect with 301 to an external URL). As 301 HTTP status code happens on the client-side so this can be compromised as the current system does not protect the integrity of the data, for instance, the amount to pay. I might send 100$ and the user might change it to 20$.

To prove this I need to stop the request manually which is very inconvenient and hard to test. I am looking for a solution that implements in one of my favorite browsers above that allows me to config to interrupt or pause the 301 HTTP status code so I can easily modify the value in the URL before resuming the request.

Comment: Are you saying that the 301 happens after a XHR or Fetch call?

Comment: Does not need to be Ajax. 301 status code will return a url to redirect to. I want to modify the URL before it redirects in an automated way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a chrome extension to solve this issue.

[Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) is easy to use and test. This is what being mentioned in the extension page:

> Chrome Extension to modify HTTP requests (Setup Redirects, Run Custom
>   Javascript, Modify Headers

But my scenario is about modifying url query string - not being mentioned in the description but it works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @channaly for the answer. Requestly can be used to setup QueryParams as you know. It is not mentioned in the description because the chrome store description has a character limit. But you have raised a valid point, I will update the chrome store details - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa and mention about Query Params Rule as well.

Comment: @sachinjain024 very useful extension. by the way in the Add/Replace params, instead of a static value can it be also a js function? My scenario is the value might be fetched or calculated from other param values, using function it will be very flexible.

Comment: No this is not yet supported. We do support some predefined functions like rq_rand(2) - To have a random number, rq_encode(string)/rq_decode(string) - To encode and decode a particular string but apart from them there is no other function supported yet.

Comment: We do provide Insert Scripts feature using which you can insert custom scripts in the page and execute your logic either before page load or after page load

Comment: @sachinjain024 Any example or blog tutorial on the Insert Scripts feature?

Comment: Here's a blog post on different rule types supported in Requestly - https://medium.com/requestly-docs/different-rule-types-in-requestly-924b49c488a4

Comment: Here's an article on Script Rule - https://medium.com/requestly-docs/inserting-scripts-dynamically-in-a-webpage-be4af90da20a

Comment: @sachinjain024 very useful.